# Was/is there animal sacrifice at dakshineshwar?

Tags: rituals, animals, sacrifice

Since it is a Kali temple, animal sacrifice probably does take place there.  Did Ramakrishna Paramahamsa sanction it?  How about Vivekananda?

Comment: You stole my question XD

Comment: There used to be animal sacrifice by private persons in Dakshineswar. I don't know the current situation.

Comment: you mean the priests won't do it routinely but if a devotees request it, it would be done?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: There is no animal sacrifices currently in Dakshineswar according to my parents.

Comment: In Ramakrishna Kathamrita, it was mentioned some account of animal sacrificing. Sometimes Sri Ramakrishna witnessed that. But nothing was mentioned about Swami Vivekananda in this regard.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath yes. I believe it is on 2nd volumen of english version (Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna). Even Sri Ramakrishna himself, say when they served him goat offered to Kali Devi, he use to touch the meat with his lips in respectfull sign to Goddess, but not eat it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, animal sactrifice used to take place at Dakshineswar Kali temple. Many evidences are there in Sri Sri Ramakrishna-leelaprasanga and Sri Sri Ramakrishna- Kathamrita.

Sri Ramakrishna approved the scriptural process of animal sacrifice wholeheartedly (Reference: Kathamrita,Akhanda Udbodhan Ed. page 144).However because of His own soft nature, He could not bear seeing it and came back to His room before the sacrifice was made.

Sri Ramakrishna left Dakshineswar in 1884. The animal sacrifice was stopped by the Temple Authorities in the 1950s so far as I know. The Yupakastha is still there.

(Reference: 1.Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Kathamrita, 2. Sri Sri Ramakrishna-Leeelaprasanga, Vol 1 & 2)